# To sort a list of numbers in an ascending order

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and trying to write a code to answer the question below:
**Create a lambda function named sort to sort a list of numbers in an ascending order.**
The output is given as:
**sort([6,2,3,9,1,5]) == [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]**
I have written the code below as my response and its working:

```
a = [6,2,3,9,1,5]
sort = list(map(lambda a:a,a))
sort.sort()
print(sort)
```

My question is this is a genuine code or I missing something?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the straightforward solution is to just say `sort = lambda x: sorted(x)`, since there's already a built-in function called `sorted` that does exactly what the `sort` function is supposed to do.  Not a very good assignment IMO.

Comment: You should write it yourself. Or at least search to find the solution. It's an easy problem. Take your time and search on google. That way you will learn more. :)

Comment: Well your lambda doesn't actually do anything so no it's not genuine. if you change it's name then you realize your issue. Your invoking the built-in `sort` method of `list` which is doing the actual work.

Comment: The assignment is asking you to create a named lambda function? That's... interesting.

Comment: @Samwise, when i use that function its not giving me an output.

Comment: `print(sort([6,2,3,9,1,5]) == [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9])` -> should print `True` if `sort` is defined correctly according to the assignment.

Comment: Sam: I have tried that code but its not giving me an output  ,MSH: I have tried looking for the same example online since yesterday but none.If you are aware of any reference, I will appreciate @TheLazyScripter.Its still working when I change the lambda name.      a = [6,2,3,9,1,5]
                                sort_list =list(map(lambda a:a,a))
                                sort_list.sort()
                                print(sort_list)

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if you're missing something, but as per the question, `sort` must be a `lambda` function;but in accordance to your code, `sort` seems like returning a `list` instead of being a `lambda` function.

The following will satisfy the question :-

```py
a = [6,2,3,9,1,5]

sort = lambda x : sorted(x)

print(sort(a))
```

Here `sort` is a `lambda` function that returns a sorted list, as asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks .You really helped.solution looks simple but to a beginner it something else

Comment: @Rony_Beginner You're always welcome, mate.